# QMainWindow - resizing problem with QGraphicsView

Tags: qt4, resize, qgraphicsview, qmainwindow

Using Qt 4.6 on Ubuntu 10.4

I have a QGraphicsView central widget in my MainWindow.  Every time the program switches to a new level (Sokoban game), I want the MainWindow to adjust to the new size of the view.  I mostly accomplished this by setting the maximum and minimum width/heights of both the mainwindow and view to the same thing, and this works most of the time, but on some smaller levels MainWindow only shrinks in one dimension, and leaves a white margin on one side like so:

[image: my Sokoban game]

It stays like that until I click in the view, at which point the MainWindow shrinks to the view.  I can enter keystrokes before that to move my guy around and perform other commands and the margin will stay, it takes a mouse click to shrink it.  I came up with a hackish fix by

```
move( geometry().x() + 1, geometry().y() ); // force mainWindow to update
move( geometry().x() - 1, geometry().y() ); // hackish but only thing that works
```

but this seems lame and most likely not portable, although I'm not sure this problem exists on other platforms.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you use [resize](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#size-prop) or [setGeometry](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) methods, your rectangle is bound by [minimum](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#minimumSize-prop) size of the widget.

By default this is 0,0 but is there any chance that you are setting minimum size in your code perhaps by the layout so that resize method rejects your given parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's all the code that I used with building and setting up the view/scene from MainWindow

```
m_scene->setSceneRect( -width/2, -height/2, width, height );

m_view = new QGraphicsView( m_scene );
m_view->setRenderHint( QPainter::Antialiasing );
m_view->setResizeAnchor( QGraphicsView::AnchorViewCenter );
m_view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy( Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff );
m_view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy( Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff );
m_view->setFixedWidth( width );
m_view->setFixedHeight( height );
setMaximumWidth( width );
setMinimumWidth( width );
setMaximumHeight( height );
setMinimumHeight( height );
setCentralWidget( m_view );
m_view->show();
move( geometry().x() + 1, geometry().y() ); // force mainWindow to update
move( geometry().x() - 1, geometry().y() ); // hackish but only thing that works
m_view->setFocus();
```

Edit: the only layout in my program (that I know about) is the implicitly constructed MainWindow layout, I haven't used any QGraphicsLayouts or the like.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better fix by the following:

```
...
setCentralWidget( m_view );
m_view->show();
activateWindow();
raise();
m_view->setFocus();
```

I noticed the margins fail to shrink when the new level view being shown has the same x dimensions as the previous, but a smaller y dimension (or vice versa), so apparently QMainWindow only adjusts its size to its child contents when both the width and height of the child widget changes, or the MainWindow receives a move event (at least on GNOME 2.x). Calling activateWindow() and raise() on the MainWindow seems to do the trick, and then I can return focus to the view.